# How to implement deferred stdout in child process without using temporary files?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stdout

I have a program (let's name it `middle`) which I can't modify.
This program performs the following sequence of steps:

- `middle` sends some text to stdout (`echo Text1`)
- `middle` invokes shell script `inner.sh` passing some text string (4 KBytes or less) as argument (`inner.sh "Deferred Message"`)
- `middle` sends some text to stdout (`echo Text2`)

My task is to create two bash scripts `outer.sh` and `inner.sh` to arrange deferred message after all the other messages generated by `middle` process.
The resulting stdout must be the following:

```
Text1
Text2
Deferred Message
```

The requirements:

- `outer.sh` should invoke `middle` (and `middle` will invoke `inner.sh`).
- `inner.sh` must remember its argument (deferred message) somewhere
- After `middle` is terminated, `outer.sh` must recall the deferred message and print it to stdout
- There will be a lot of `outer.sh` processes running simultaneously.  The deferred message must be stored in a place which is local to current instance of `outer.sh` process
- Creation of temporary objects in file system is prohibited.  (Is it possible to store the deferred message somewhere in memory?)

---

**inner.sh**

```
# Where should I save message "$1"?
```

---

**outer.sh**

```
middle "$@"
# How should I recall and print the deferred message?
```

---

Where should I save the deferred message in child process and how to read it back in parent process?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`inner.sh` could be:

```
printf '%s\n' "$1" >&3
```

and in `outer.sh`, you could do:

```
{ inner=$(middle "$@" 3>&1 >&4 4>&-); } 4>&1
printf '%s\n' "$inner"
```

The inner text is passed via a pipe (in the command substitution) and stored in a shell variable. That assumes `middle` doesn't close that fd 3 before invoking `inner.sh` (no reason it would do that though).

Explanation:

- `{ ... } 4>&1`. In that command group, initially, both fd 1 and 4 point to the original stdout. IOW, we've made a copy of outer.sh's stdout onto fd 4 to be able to recover it inside the command substitution
- `$(...)`. Inside that command substitution, stdout (fd 1) is a pipe. That's the point of command substitution. It wants to grab the output of the command. But here, we don't want the stdout of `middle`, we want what it (or more exactly its child `inner.sh`) writes on fd 3, so:
- `middle 3>&1 >&4 4>&-`: for `middle`, we make fd 3 the cmdsubst pipe, so that what `inner.sh` writes there goes into `$inner`, and we restore `middle`'s stdout onto the *saved* original stdout on fd 4. We close fd 4 after it has served it's purpose as `middle` doesn't need to do anything with it.